# Under what circumstances does TypeBuilder.CreateType call AppDomain.OnTypeResolveEvent?

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

According to [the documentation of `System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.createtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If the enclosing type contains a field that is a value type defined as a nested type (for example, a field that is an enumeration defined as a nested type), calling the CreateType method on the enclosing type will generate a AppDomain.TypeResolve event.

I'm trying to debug a compiler that's raising this event under a completely different (and completely undocumented!) circumstance: I have an interface (which cannot contain fields or nested types), and one of the methods on the interface has a generic parameter with a specific-type constraint on it.  `TypeResolve` is asking for the type of that constraint.

The debugger says the call stack looks like this:

```
System.AppDomain.OnTypeResolveEvent
System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock
System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateType
My.Compiler.TypeCreator.HandleTypeCreation
```

But neither the debugger's decompilation of `TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock` nor [the reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/typebuilder.cs) shows where this call is taking place.  In fact, searching the reference source file for "TypeResolve" yields nothing at all, which means something "magic" is going on.

Where can I find out what the actual logic is here that's raising this `TypeResolve` event, so I can fix the compiler implementation to handle it?

Comment: In such cases I grep the coreclr or SSCLI code for `TypeResolve`. I'm surprised that your SSCLI search turned up nothing. My coreclr search did.

Comment: What kind of type constraint are you using? Has the type that is used for it been created yet? To me it looks like the runtime must raise this event when you have not been creating types in dependency order. The decompiled CreateTypeNoLock code shows that it calls CreateType on all generic argument types.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [AppDomain.TypeResolve Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.typeresolve.aspx) in the documentation.
Under remarks it states:

> The TypeResolve event occurs when the common language runtime is unable to determine the assembly that can create the requested type.

On the [`OnTypeResolveEvent` Method in the Referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/appdomain.cs,6add6f3506b6c23c) is this comment:

> // This method is called by the VM

When you use the example from the msdn entry and put a breakpoint on the `OnTypeResolveEvent` method you will get a stacktrace like this:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.OnTypeResolveEvent(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly assembly, string typeName)
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscorlib.dll!System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(string name, bool throwOnError, bool ignoreCase, bool reflectionOnly, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, System.IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, bool loadTypeFromPartialName)
mscorlib.dll!System.RuntimeType.GetType(string typeName, bool throwOnError, bool ignoreCase, bool reflectionOnly, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark)
mscorlib.dll!System.Type.GetType(string typeName, bool throwOnError)
ResolveTest.exe!Test.Main()
```

So i think it is pretty clear this event will be invoked by the runtime itself and not by one specific function in the framework libraries.

To handle this situation it should be enough to put your own delegate on the `AppDomain.TypeResolve`event and help the runtime by providing the missing Type.